# Smart contract crowdfunding

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have a question concerning the smart contracts. I have a crowdfunding ICO idea to implement. It has a three date ranges to purchase tokens in a presale. 
 
For example: 
 
Total tokens - 300 000 
Crowdfunding starts at 01.06.2018 
There is a limit of 100 000 ICO until 10.06.2018 (50% price) 
Another limit of 100 000 ICO 10.06.2018 - 20.06.2018 (75% price) 
 
100 000 after 20.06.2018 (100% price)

I'm not sure how to implement a resale. Does it have to be implemented within one contract from the beginning (with startPresaleOneDate, endPresaleOnedate, startPresaleTwoDate, endPresaleTwoDate ... ) or is it possible to prepare a #1 presale contract with total of 100 000 tokens and 50% price, #2 presale contract after that, and #last contract at the end ? 
In the end I want all the coins to reach the investors.

Comment: You can do either of those things. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: In case of creating separate contract for each sale, I want to be sure that in the end all contributors will receive their tokens (same tokens). Reading your reply I guess there is no problem with that :) one more question about token proce. I have a price 0.035$ for 1 token, but receive Ether in my contract, how to calculate the exact amount of tokens for contributor with the current Ether price?

Answer (score 0):

You can write one function for the implementation of the logic and within the function, you restrict the coins as per your requirement.